# watch for db changes from rails application

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

my app is developed from 2 parts - rails frontend and java backend. Backend can modify db (add, modify or remove records) and i'm looking for a solution - how to monitor changes in db from frontend to push it to the clients. Of course - i can add code to backend to call for some method via http get, but maybe you can recommend me something better?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by Rails is the "frontend"? Do you have APIs? Just using it for rendering views? Do you have a javascript application for the client side?

Comment: What do you mean "javascript application for the client side"? I have used standart terms (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends) - rails app is interacting with user and java app is interacting with other services. I just need to inform frontend to push information (via faye) to user about changes in db (for example - new record).

Comment: Rails is an MVC framework and handles views for the front end, and controllers and models for the back end. Why are you splitting this functionality into two separate parts? Either one can handle both. What I mean by a JS app is that there has to be something running on the client side (typically JavaScript) that makes server requests to update the view. Neither Rails nor Java can do this, and if you want to push data, you'd need something like web sockets.

Comment: you don't understand me :) i mean frontend and backend BOTH ON SERVER, but not server and browser :) as example - java or node.js app that receiving data from external sources (such as sms gateways etc) and adding to database. And frontend for users that displays this data to user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the Faye gem. Checkout http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye. You need to build a "caller" in the java app that calls a Faye function once data is processed. Then let faye push data to the clients.

Added:
Build an API controller with a action within your rails app that your JAVA app calls whenever it updates the data. The API action can then use Faye to push data to the rails "clients".

If you implement it this way you can be very specific in your calls from the Java app and only update clients that needs to be updated. You can also add other sophistication, for instance if your data gets updated very often, you can queue updates and push them at certain configurable intevals. etc etc.

Comment: i'm already using faye to push data update from rails app %) i need to inform rails app about changes from backend, to push updates to clients with browser

Comment: This is kind of what I meant. Build an API controller with a action that your JAVA app calls whenever it updates the data. The API action can then use Faye to push data to the rails "clients".

Comment: i'm already did it :) but in future i'm planning to add cross-messaging thru redis, because i will be need for bi-directional integration (notifications pushing)

Comment: As of 2022, unless limited by some other factors, ActionCable should be the preferred approach for pushing real-time updates from a Rails backend to the client-side. ActionCable is now supported out of the box by Rails.